# Distribution mod n of the values of Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory

Given an odd integer $n>1$, is anything known about the limiting distribution among residue classes mod $n$ of the values of the sequence $\phi(k)$, $k=2,3,\ldots$?  As mentioned in the comments, for n=3 the distribution doesn't look uniform. For large values of $n$ uniform distribution looks vaguely plausible.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand you, but my experiments do not support this claim.  For $k$ between 2 and 1000000, I find $\phi(k)$ is congruent to 0 mod 3 733,529 times, to 1 mod 3 170224 times, and to 2 mod 3 96,246 times. This doesn't suggest an even distribution.

Comment: Take a look at this paper by Carl Pomerance and Thomas Dence: http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper116.pdf (though it has some weird typesetting errors...)

Comment: @Matthew. Thank you. I've edited to make the question more reasonable.

Comment: @Matthew. That paper looks right on the mark.